# Spark (v2) does not generate output if the size is more than 2 GB

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My Spark application writes outputs that range from several KBs to GBs. I have been facing problem in generating output for certain cases when the file size appears to be more than 2 GB, wherein nothing seems to happen. I hardly see any CPU usage. However, in case where the output size is less than 2 GB, such as 1.3 GB, the same application works flawlessly.  Also, please note that writing output is the last stage and all the computations using the data to be written gets correctly and completely processed (as can be seen from debug output) -- hence driver storing the data is not an issue. Besides, the size of the executor memory is also not an issue as I had increased it even to 90 GB while 30GB also seems to be adequate. The following is the code I am using to write the output. Please suggest any way to fix it.

```
var output = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
...
output.toDF().coalesce(1).toDF().write.mode("overwrite")
         .option("parserLib","univocity").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false")
         .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").format("csv").save(outputPath)
```

Other related parameters passed by spark-submit are as follows:

```
--driver-memory 150g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 30g \
--conf spark.cores.max=252 \
--conf spark.local.dir=/tmp \
--conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=2047 \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=50g \
```

The issue was observed on two different systems, one standalone and the other which is a spark cluster.

Comment: I see that you run `output.toDF()` - How did you generate the data on driver? Is it an a result of other dataframe collection? If so, does the failure happen during this `collect` operation?

Comment: The data was obtained from earlier transformations and actions based on large data. When I only write a part of the output, it works. The DF has been validated. I also tried `unpersist`ing the earlier cached data from all the executors. This approach also did not work.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your code does but if you try to collect a lot of data to the driver, increasing `spark.driver.maxResultSize` may help

Comment: The data size that I estimate is less than 15 GB. Will try this too, sounds meaningful.

Comment: The driver shows (web UI) Storage/Memory as 77 KB/86 GB respectively. I increased the maxResultSize to 140GB with no luck. I have a couple of questions. (a) Can I use Scala directly to write output file in Spark 2? (b) Is there a limit on max output size in Spark?

Comment: (a) - I wouldn't go this way. (b) - no limit afaik.

Comment: Did you try to repartition the dataframe before the write operation?

Comment: I tried removing the `coalesce(1)` in the first line given above with no avail.

Comment: I have partitioned the data, printed the number of partitions (to force the action) and wrote the output in partitions itself. It worked. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gabio's idea of reparitioning, I solved the problem as follows:

```
val tDF = output.toDF()
println("|#tDF partitions = " + tDF.rdd.partitions.size.toString)

tDF.write.mode("overwrite")
    .option("parserLib","univocity").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false")
    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").format("csv").save(outputPath)
```

The output ranged between 2.3 GB and 14 GB, so the source of the problem is elsewhere and perhaps not in `spark.driver.maxResultSize`.

A big thank you to @Gabio!